# Increase Container height dynamically based on content inside card widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to increase `Container` height dynamically based on content in `card` widget inside `ListView.builder`. I want the `container` to increase its height based on content but problem is `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,` inside `listview.builder`. How to solve this issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      height: height * 0.200, // Here i have to put some height to show card 
      child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              child: Card(
                  elevation: 0,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, right: 5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.near_me,
                              size: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '1 km',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 80.0,
                                width: 80.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 10.0, right: 35.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: width * 0.40,
                                    child: Text(
                                      'test',
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          'test',
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.5),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.location_on_outlined,
                                          size: 12.0,
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          width: width * 0.40,
                                          child: Text(
                                            'test',
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            maxLines: 1,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your Column widget gives overflow error wrap it inside `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: you used fixed length that's you got the error. `SingleChildScrollView ` will not solve your issue